# Does a child component unmount in react when parent rerenders?

Tags: reactjs

Hi i observed a strange thing during one of my projects, which i think changes my understanding of th react renders, just what to confirm if i am right...,

i am passing function into useState hook to set initial state, in a child component

```
const [state,setState] = useState(()=>initialStateFn());
```

my understanding is that initialStateFn will run on every mount of the component,
and i was of the belief that child would remount when parent component rerenders causing the initialStateFn to run again, but it seems though the parent rerenders the initialStateFn does not run, it is as if child was not unmounted..., so wanted some clarity here, about what causes a child to remount

Comment: A component is only unmounted if it shouldn't be rendered anymore. Otherwise it just "updated" (rerenders).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Felix Kling, I believe it clears some of my doubt, a new one arises though, that if a 2 children are associated with different states in parent, eg. Parent has state variables A and B, A is passed as prop to child A component and B is passed as prop to child B component, then if state A is changed, would it cause just A to rerender or both A and B will rerender. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Maybe these articles help: https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html , https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#avoid-reconciliation

Comment: A very big thank you man, u really helped a lot. I understand react so much better now, because of u. Really appreciated.

Comment: You're very welcome :)